# How can I have a constrained operator template?

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to make my class convertible to any enum type.

```
enum dst_1 { /*...*/ };
enum dst_2 { /*...*/ };
class src { /*...*/ };

src s;
dst_1 d1 = s;
dst_2 d2 = s;
```

I do **not want to manually** add conversions for each enum type, so the following is not an acceptable solution:

```
// OK, but tedious - you must consider each enum type
class src
{
public:
  operator dst_1() const { /*...*/ }
  operator dst_2() const { /*...*/ }
  // ...
};
```

Making the conversion a template does not work for the template parameter **cannot be deduced**:

```
// NOT OK: T cannot be deduced
class src
{
public:
  template< typename T > using Enum = enable_if_t< is_enum_v< T >, T >;
  template< typename T > operator Enum< T >() const { /*...*/ }
};
```

The **only solution I could find is a variadic template**, but I do not like it for it forces the user to specify the enums is planning to use:

```
// ALMOST OK, but still tedious - you must know in advance what enums will be used
src< dst_1, dst_2 > s;
dst_1 d1 = s;
dst_2 d2 = s;
```

***So, is there a better solution?*** Ideally I would like to write:

```
src s;
dst_1 d1 = s;
dst_2 d2 = s;
```

Comment: And the down-voting is for...?

Comment: What does it mean to convert your class to an enumeration?  What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: what do you mean by "conversion of a class to any enum"? how would class know which enum value to convert into?

Comment: @NathanOliver I wolud like the cast operator to be automatically called.

Comment: But what would the operator do? What is meant by converting the object to an enum?

Comment: I don't think it really matters what the conversion does. It could be simply a conversion of some stored integer value. Terrible design (The language has been moving away from implicit conversions for a reason) , but doable.

Comment: @Kevin Not important. The actual class is reading some values from a dictionary like file

Comment: @ZDF its quite important, what if later user of this class will try to use it with "unsupported" enum? for me it looks like XY problem, and while it could be implement as academical exercise - its better to use explicit conversions or even totally different approach

Comment: @IłyaBursov I do not quite understand what _"unsupported" enum_ means - some distant future standard change? I am not a meta-programming guru; I simply want to write `others_enum e = dictionary_file["key"]`. It is not my design, it is an old project, I do not have a lot of freedom, etc. - real world. Still I am curious about why (not who) the question was down-voted.

Comment: @ZDF no, I'm not speaking about standard change, I mean if another user defined some `enum q {A, B}` and later use `q t = s;` what value should appear in t?

Comment: I feel like the question: "How do I solve this problem?" is sufficiently clear and interesting in of itself, and the question "Why do I want to solve this problem?" is mostly off-topic music. We get all sorts of absurdly precise metaprogramming related questions that have minimal use - I don't see why this one, which is basically "How can I have a constrained operator template?" merits downvoting.

Comment: @Barry I would like to change the title of the question to _"How can I have a constrained operator template?"_, if you don't mind.

Comment: @ZDF I mean, it's your question :-) I just wanted to get rid of the word "default" because it doesn't really mean anything in this context.

Comment: @Barry My question - your contribution.

Comment: @IłyaBursov The value stored in dictionary under the associated key, if any, or the default value the user selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Making the conversion a template does not work for the template parameter cannot be deduced:

It cannot be deduced in the way you did it because `T` is a non-deduced context here:

```
template< typename T > using Enum = enable_if_t< is_enum_v< T >, T >;
```

This can't be deduced for the same way that this cannot deduce `T`:

```
template <typename T> struct identity { using type = T; }

template <typename T> void foo(typename identity<T>::type);
foo(0); // nope
```

---

The correct way to write this operator template is:

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<T>, int> = 0>
operator T() const;
```

Or alternatively:

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<T>, int> = 0> using Enum = T;
template <typename T> operator Enum<T>() const;
```

Note that the alias *has* to be `T`, not anything else.

Comment: Thank you, Barry. I would replace `int` with `underlying_type_t<T>`.

Comment: @ZDF: no need, that `int` is unrelated to enum, but used to allow to default the SFINAE type.

Comment: @Jarod42 Pfff... I finally understood it. Thank you.